# Running ASP.NET 4.6 on IIS 10 HTTP error 500

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, hosting

I have a running server (Windows Server 2008) with some ASP.NET services hosted on IIS. Now I have a new server (Windows Server 2019) with IIS 10. I try to move all services to the new server. All services written with .net core 3.x are running without problems.
Some older services written in .NET 4.6 are not running correctly. When I try to access them I am always getting HTTP-Error 500, but without details.
I have already changed the web.config files, but I still get no more details.

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>
```

The event viewer in Windows is also empty.
In the Server Manager .NET is correctly installed. Firewall ports are open.

Has someone some hints what I maybe have missed to configure? And is there another place where I can find more detailed errors?

best regards

Comment: Have you checked under event viewer logs unders Application and System categories? Also, can you share you application pool settings? Ensure the user which is set as AppPool identity has minimum read permissions on your application folder

Comment: Modify the web apps to handle exceptions, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/processing-unhandled-exceptions-cs#:~:text=When%20an%20unhandled%20exception%20occurs%20in%20an%20ASP.NET,the%20Exception%20Details%20YSOD%3B%20and%20custom%20error%20pages.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install the asp.net 4.6 feature from the add role and feature wizard as shown below:

[image]

Comment: The frameworks are correctly installed, this is not the problem.

Comment: @BHuelse you could check the iis log which sub status code it is showing. check the iis application pool which version it is using? if possible share the whole web.config file code. enable failed request tracing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/benjaminperkins/enable-and-activate-failed-request-tracing-rules. try to browse any page in a browser

Comment: This suggestion definitely helped me. The only difference was that in my list of features it was ASP.NET 4.7.